# Algorithm to parse an int from a string in one pass

Tags: c, algorithm, parsing

I'm trying to write a function that parses an integer from a string representation.

My problem is that I don't know how to do this with one pass through the string. If I knew ahead of time that the input contained only characters in the range `'0'`, `'1'`, ..., `'9'` and that the string was of length `n`, I could of course calculate

```
character_1 * 10^(n-1) + character_2 * 10^(n-2) + .... + character_n * 10^0
```

but I want to deal with the general scenario as I've presented it.

I'm not looking for a library function, but an algorithm to achieve this in "pure C".

Here's the code I started from:

```
int parse_int (const char * c1, const char * c2, int * i)
{
    /*
        [c1, c2]: Range of characters in the string
               i: Integer whose string representnation will be converted

        Returns the number of characters parsed. 

        Exs. "2342kjsd32" returns 4, since the first 4 characters were parsed.
             "hhsd3b23" returns 0
    */

    int n = 0;
    *i = 0;
    while (c1!= c2)
    {
        char c = *c1;
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {

        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: inside if condition `n = n*10 + (c-'0');`

Comment: Does `Pure C, so no libraries` include ignoring the standard libraries?

Comment: @Lashane That won't work. For instance, if the string is "123" then it will be calculated as 1+20+300=321.

Comment: This seems like a "please write my code for me" question... Frankly, it looks like the code in question is a skeleton provided by someone else, and you're supposed to fill it in... If it's your own code, then just keep coding, and ask when you have actual problem or error. Current code is just incomplete, it does not seem to have actual problem in it!

Comment: @SteveBallmer it *will* work. On "123", first iteration is *i = 0*10 + ('1' - '0'), and this is 1; second iteration will be *i = 1*10 + ('2' - '0'), this makes 12; third iteration will be *i = 12*10 + ('3' - '0'), and the final result is 123.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as some of the comments and answers suggested, maybe a bit clearer: You have to "shift" the result "left" by multiplying it by 10 in every iteration before the addition of the new digit.

Indeed, this should remind us of [Horner's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method). As you have recognized, the result can be written like a polynomial:

```
result = c1 * 10^(n-1) + c2 * 10^(n-2) + ... + cn * 10^0
```

And this equation can be rewritten as this:

```
result = cn + 10*(... + 10*(c2 + 10*c1))
```

Which is the form this approach is based on. From the formula you can already see, that you don't need to know the power of 10 the first digit is to be multiplied by, directly from the start.

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int parse_int(const char * begin, const char * end, int * result) {
    int d = 0;
    for (*result = 0; begin != end; d++, begin++) {
        int digit = *begin - '0';
        if (digit >= 0 && digit < 10) {
            *result *= 10;
            *result += digit;
        }
        else break;
    }
    return d;
}

int main() {
    char arr[] = "2342kjsd32";
    int result;
    int ndigits = parse_int(arr, arr+sizeof(arr), &result);
    printf("%d digits parsed, got: %d\n", ndigits, result);
    return 0;
}
```

The same can be achieved using `sscanf()`, for everyone that is fine with using the C standard library (can also handle negative numbers):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char arr[] = "2342kjsd32";
    int result, ndigits;
    sscanf(arr, "%d%n", &result, &ndigits);
    printf("%d digits parsed, got: %d\n", ndigits, result);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is (both implementations):

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out
4 digits parsed, got: 2342
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is good solution to count parse character

```
int parse(char *str)
{
    int k = 0;
    while(*str)
    {
        if((*str >= '0') & (*str <= '9'))
            break;
        str++;
        k++;
    }
    return k;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int parse_int (const char * c1, const char * c2, int * i)
{
   /*
      [c1, c2]: Range of characters in the string
             i: Integer whose string representnation will be converted

      Returns the number of characters parsed. 

      Exs. "2342kjsd32" returns 4, since the first 4 characters were parsed.
      "hhsd3b23" returns 0
    */

   int n = 0;
   *i = 0;
   for (; c1 != c2; c1++)
   {
      char c = *c1;
      if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
      {
         ++n;
         *i = *i * 10 + c - '0';
      }
      else
      {
         break;
      }
   }

   return n;
}

int main()
{
   int i;
   char const* c1 = "2342kjsd32";
   int n = parse_int(c1, c1+10, &i);
   printf("n: %d, i: %d\n", n, i);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
n: 4, i: 2342
```

Comment: I don't understand the reasons for the downvotes. Did I misunderstand the question?